# How to use right gutenprint driver in ghostscript?

Tags: printing, driver, ghostscript, epson, printer-control-language

For a research project about printing nanofluids with an Piezo electric printer I want to see the the code that the computer sends to the printer. I am running Ubuntu 16.04 and have an Epson Stylus SX600FW printer.
Using Ghostscript 9.18 I want to print a simple ps file and obtain the output file that is being send to the printer. This file should contain some ESC/P sequences if I am right. Now I have some problems with the rigth driver is Ghostscript.

I want to print the file using : `gs -sDEVICE=epson -sOutputFile=%pipe%lpr test.ps`. The printer starts the print gibberish. Just some letters and symbols on page, not the two words that are in my `test.ps`.

So probably ghostscript doesn't use the rigth driver. How can I get gs to use the `escp2-of-sx600fw` or `Epson-Stylus_Office_SX600FW` driver, as stated on the gutenprint site?

Kind Regards Rick

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a non-standard device, then you will have to rebuild Ghostscript and tell it to include the device's source in the build.

Nobody has supplied us with source to an Epson SX600FW device, so we don't supply it, not even in the contrib directory. There is a 'vector' Espon device in there, but its not built in as standard.

Looks like Gutenprint itself drives the printer. Presumably it only uses Ghostscript to render PostScript and PDF files into some intermediate format that it can then convert onwards to the specified device format. If I'm right, then you can't make Ghostscript use the Gutenprint device driver, as that will be specific to GutenPrint. You'll have to use Gutenprint to do that.

Comment: Okay, I understand that the exact Epson printer I am using is not included in ghostscript. Looking at the ghostprint manual (http://www.ghostscript.com/doc/9.06/Devices.htm#gimp-print) I was hopeful that gimp-print maybe could solve the driver issue, as stated on their webite. But since I think I wont't be able to rebuild Ghostscript because of my Linux skills...

Is there a way using CUPS (already using the right driver via `lp`) to obtain the file that is being sent to the printer?

Comment: I'm reasonably certain you can have CUPS redirect the output to a file, or capture the data in transit. However I'm not enough of a CUPS expert to be able to give you details. I'd look at the CUPS website to see if anything there will help, I have a feeling there's something useful in the section on debugging, or possibly on reporting a problem.